# stuck with loop or something else?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, each

I think I am making some mistakes when it comes to loop function. I have a quiz and i have four options. Every time I have chosen an answer and clicked on "nästa" it will store the selected answer, but in case if they change their mind and want back all the options they can click on the button "visa alla alternativ". To check if I am doing right I have appended which question it has been appeared. Every time I click on "nästa" the number of question will appear.

eg. 1 2 3 4 (I have clicked four time and four different question has been appeared).

But if I click on "visa alla alternativ" the number will be like this. 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4. It depends on how many times I have clicked on "visa alla alternativ".

```
var answer = [];
var select; 

$(".option").on("click", click_question);

function nästa() {

    answer.push(select); 
    count_click();

    $(".option").each(function() {
        $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1);
        $(this).on("click", click_question);
    });

    $(this).fadeTo("slow", 0.2);
    $("#visa_alternativ").fadeTo("slow", 0.2);
    $("#tillbaka_question").fadeTo("slow", 1);

    clicks.length = 1;
}

function click_question() {

        $(".option").each(function() {
            $(this).fadeTo("slow", 0.1);
        });

        $(".option").off("click");

        $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1); 

        $("#visa_alternativ").fadeTo("slow", 1);
        $("#nästa").fadeTo("slow", 1);
        $("#nästa").on("click", nästa);

        select = $(this).text();
}

$("#visa_alternativ").on("click", function () {
            $(".option").each(function() {
                $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1);
            });

            $(".option").on("click", click_question);
            $(this).fadeTo("slow", 0.2);
            $("#nästa").fadeTo("slow", 0.2);
});
```

It is somehow that the function calls `count_click();`, where the function get us a random question. `count_click();` is working properly but if I click on "Visa alla alternativ" it is calling more question depending on how many times I click on "visa alla anlternativ". Once before I had done something wrong with the `each()` and I asked the question here, but now I get similar problem but little bit different. I need help and tell me what I am doing wrong with the `each()` function ?

EDIT:

Well,  found that if I put $("#nästa").on("click", nästa); outside of the function it is working, but not when I put it into the function, as you can see above? WHY?

Comment: I would advice you to avoid swedish characters in function and variable names, even if it is valid and does work.

Comment: Yes, I made this code in the beginning, but I will avoid to use it in the future. But do you understand my question?

Comment: Yes, but it's a bit involved and it's a little hard to see exactly what the code does and what the issue is. I can't see any obvious errors at first glance, but maybe if you tried setting up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are binding the `click_question` function multiple times (which means it will run multiple times):

```
$(".option").on("click", click_question); // bound to each .option here
function nästa() {
    answer.push(select);
    count_click();
    $(".option").each(function () {
        $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1);
        $(this).on("click", click_question); // bound again as .each iterates through them.
    });
    $(this).fadeTo("slow", 0.2);
    $("#visa_alternativ").fadeTo("slow", 0.2);
    $("#tillbaka_question").fadeTo("slow", 1);
    clicks.length = 1;
}
```

Either don't bind multiple times, or use [`.one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) instead of [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: Yes, I found out that I should not have put $("#nästa").on("click", nästa); into the click_question... But why? Because I want the "nästa" to be clickable once they have chosen an option. If I put $("#nästa").on("click", nästa); outside the function it will work either if you have chosen an option or not.